# Angular JS - How to change the value of an input from the event of another element

Tags: angularjs, umbraco8

I have this html:

```
<div ng-controller="My.MarkdownEditorController">
  <a target="_default" ng-click="changeValue()" class="btn btn-info">Copy Organisation Address to Member</a>
</div>
```

The Angular controller for the click is:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("My.MarkdownEditorController",
  function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.changeValue = function () {

      //changes value but it doesn't save
      //what is the Angular way to do this correctly
      document.getElementById('title').value= document.getElementById('title').value + '2';

    };

  });
```

How do I change the value of the adjacent text box with id "title" correctly?
The above code modifies the value, but it doesn't save.
I think that's because I am not changing it the Angular way.

The html of the input I am trying to modify is:

```
<input type="text" id="title" name="textbox" ng-model="model.value" class="umb-property-editor umb-textstring textstring ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-val-server ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" val-server="value" ng-required="model.validation.mandatory" aria-required="false" aria-invalid="False" ng-trim="false" ng-keyup="change()">
```

[image]

Comment: You may have to use [$document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$document) instead of `document` and you may also have to use [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Answer (score 0):

I got this working but not sure if it is correct:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("My.MarkdownEditorController",
  function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.changeValue = function () {

      var title = $("#title");
      title.val("this is how to do it");
      setTimeout(function(){ title.trigger("input") }, 10);


    };

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your input: `<alue" ng-keyup="change()">`

You have javascript value `model.value` and html input value. These two are connected via `ng-model`:

- After you change scope value `$scope.model.value = ...` angularjs will update html input value.
- After user changes html input value, angularjs will update your scope value.

You should nealy never change html input value directly, you should change scope value (it wont trigger `ng-keyup` or `ng-change`).

P.S. avoid using `ng-keyup` in inputs - there is copy-paste and drag-drop that may change input as well.